# wpf datagrid заполнить из List

Tags: wpf, datagrid

программа выдает ошибку "Ключ не может быть неопределенным." и не указывает строку с ошибкой

```
public class grItem {
    public string ttl { get; set; }
    public int cnt1 { get; set; }
    public int cnt2 { get; set; }
    public int cnt3 { get; set; }
    public int cnt4 { get; set; }
    public int cnt5 { get; set; }
    public int cnt6 { get; set; }
}

List<grItem> readyItems = new List<grItem>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> dic in mainListNight){
    Dictionary<string, int> d = dic.Value;

    grItem gi = new grItem
            {
                ttl = dic.Key,
                cnt1 = d["0-1"],
                cnt2 = d["1-4"],
                cnt3 = d["4-7"],
                cnt4 = d["7-15"],
                cnt5 = d["15-17"],
                cnt6 = d["17-18"]
            };

    readyItems.Add(gi);
}

dgvNight.ItemsSource = readyItems;

<DataGrid x:Name="dgvNight" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
    Height="400"
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"

    >
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
 <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                        Value="LightGray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ttl}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="МКБ" Width="100">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt1}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="0-1" 
                                Width="100">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                    Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt2}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="1-4" 
                                Width="100">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                                    Value="LightGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt3}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="4-7" 
                                Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt4}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="7-15" 
                                Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt5}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="15-17" 
                                Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding cnt6}" 
                                ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" 
                                Header="17-18" 
                                Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный код на котором проблема воспроизводится, сомневаюсь, что в приведенном коде прям каждая строчка важна

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил в вопрос стили которые вызвали проблему

Answer (score 0):

проблема оказалась в стилях

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                        Value="LightGray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

после удаления таблица заполняется

Comment: Вы не указали Binding в триггере

Comment: @АндрейNOP не могли бы подсказать правильный вариант? биндинги плохо понимаю

Comment: Так откуда ж я знаю как правильно? На какое свойство вы триггер вешаете?

Comment: @Андрей NOP <DataTrigger Value="0"> написал же. Если в ячейке 0

Comment: Не, DataTrigger так не работает, у него надо указывать привязку `Binding` и значение `Value` сравнивается в ним. Скорее всего вам нужен обычный триггер с `Property="Content"`